# Extending magento category

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-community

I am extending magento 1 category edit page, adding tab and fields. What is the best approach for this?
Using built in EAV system or save the values in a custom table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to used built in EAV system to save category field value.

You can create fields like this.

```
$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'attribute_id', array(
    'group'         => 'General Information',
    'input'         => 'select',
    'source'        => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'label'         => 'Attribute Label',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
));
```

This is sample code for you.